# URL does not load in uiWebView but takes too long to load in wkWebView and Safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am running into an issue where URLs are not loading in `uiWebView`. While loading in `uiWebView` the page freezes and have to resort to killing the application to reuse the `webView`.

The URL loads in `wkWebView` and `Safari` but takes about 1 minute to completely load the page.

URL: http://my.gateway3d.com/acp/app/?l=acp2&c=tzxmnn4hp4df5mb#p=1086474&guid=15254&pc=16483&r=webgl&ep3dUrl=http://www.casehype.gateway3d.com/personalise-it/product/callback&epa=http://my.gateway3d.com/acp/api/p/2/epa/get/p/

Comment: What URL are we talking about? Maybe add it to your question, if privacy allows you that.

Comment: have added the URL to the question.